# DataTables - filter an unsearchable column

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I have a [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) table like this:

```
id | name | group
---+------+-------
1  | Jump | Action
2  | Hop  | Unused
```

The Group column is unsearchable. But I want to remove rows in the 'Unused' Group (but they can be added back with a btn click).

```
dt.columns(2).search('Unused').draw()
```

This doesn't seem to work.